# How can I create a time-based Makefile rule?

Tags: time, makefile, dependencies

I would like to have a Makefile target that gets rebuilt only if the target file is older than some time interval.

As an example, say that I have some way of generating a key that is valid for one day, but  generating it takes a non-trivial amount of time. I could just regenerate it each time I needed it:

```
.PHONY: key
key:
    sleep 5 && echo generated > key
foo: key
    echo foo
bar: key
    echo bar
```

But, over the course of the day, I might type `make foo` or `make bar` quite a few times. Waiting each time is annoying, and I would rather just eat this cost once per day.

Answer (score 4):

Have the generated file depend on some dummy file like `key-timestamp`, then have a cron job `touch` that file every day.

Comment: While I believe this would work, it would require extra setup on the part of every developer who wanted to compile this code. If the cron entry wasn't setup, then the build would start failing whenever the key expired.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping a sentinel file that is computed during the make run?

```
sentinel_file_prefix  = sentinel_file.stamp
sentinel_file         = $(sentinel_file_prefix).$(shell date +%Y%m%d)

file_to_regenerate_every_day: $(sentinel_file)
    echo Usual make recipe

$(sentinel_file):
    - rm $(sentinel_file_prefix).* 
    touch $@
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.PHONY: key.update key.check

foo: key.check
    echo foo

bar: key.check
    echo bar

key.check: key
    @find key -mmin +1440 -exec make key.update \;

key:
    make key.update

key.update:
    sleep 5 && echo generated > key
```

Should work as expected, if you don't have access to `find` you must replace it with something similar. Basically, replace it by something that will detect that key have been last modified 1 days or more ago.

[`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets) will force the rule to run.

I also dig into [`order-only-prerequisites`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types), this need to run the makefile twice at hand to update the key only one every 24 hours. Not very practical.

This is however a trick I would not recommend it as a normal use of a makefile.

Answer (score -1):

To rebuild a make target after a certain time, you would need a helper file, depend on that and touch the helper by force, like (example is daily):

```
target:  target.helper
    script-or-rule

target.helper: FORCE
    @touch -d -1day $@

FORCE:
```

Comment: This appears to require GNU `touch`, as on macOS: `touch: illegal option -- d`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to solve the problem. If I add `sleep 5` to either of your rules and run `make target`, it takes 5 seconds for each run, not 5 seconds once and then instant.

Comment: Adding a sleep command this way should only delay things by 5 second nothing more. IMHO this leads not to where you described to go.    
  
A possible replacement for the `touch` command could be `perl` here like:    
`@perl -e ' $$t = time - 3600*24; utime $$t, $$t, $@'`  
Please note, this line is already quoted for a makefile  
  
Btw. ".PHONY" is also a gnu extension to the `make` command.

Comment: Yes, it will delay the execution by 5 seconds every time `make` is executed. The point of the question: *I would rather just eat this cost once per day*. The 5 seconds should occur only once in every 24 period.

Comment: Sorry I am lost than. I am sure my Makefile fixes your initial request "rebuilt only if the target file is older than some time interval". No sleep is needed, no cronjob, just the Makefile, my example time interval here is "1 day". However it seems to me you are coming up with a slightly different problem statement. It would help if you could rephrase your problem statement in that case.

Comment: The `sleep` in the original question is a placeholder for an operation that takes time (generating a license key). The license key is valid for a fixed amount of time (1 week). The simplest thing to do is to regenerate the key every time a rule needs it, but this means that invocations of make that need that key will waste time regenerating the key when it is still valid. Instead, I want to regenerate the key only once per day — frequently enough to ensure it is always valid, but infrequently enough that I don't have to wait 5 seconds for every `make foo`.